# movement on object click

Tags: unity-game-engine, onmousedown

On pressing down the object I want it to move continuously.I am a beginner in Unity 3D.
Please help.

```
function OnMouseDown()
{
      Debug.Log("its a hit");

       function Update()
    {
    transform.Translate(Vector3(0,0,3)*Time.deltaTime);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Unity Answer for several approaches on how to drag an object with the mouse:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12322/drag-gameobject-with-mouse.html

Answer (score 0):

Just click the mouse

```
   function Update() 
   {
     if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //Left click
     {
        Debug.Log("Left Mouse Button Click");
        transform.Translate(Vector3(0,0,3)*Time.deltaTime);
      }
   }
```

Or with select object

```
   function Update() 
   {
     if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //Left click
     {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, hit))
        {
         hit.collider.gameObject.Translate(Vector3(0,0,3)*Time.deltaTime);
        }
     }
   }
```